# Amazon s3 connector: IllegalArgumentException: Empty key when using getAuthorization

Tags: amazon-s3, wso2, connector, wso2-esb

When using the getAuthorization function from the Amazon s3 connector I am getting the following trace:

```
 [2016-04-28 11:42:14,155] ERROR - AmazonS3AuthConnector Error occured in connect
or
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty key
        at javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec.<init>(SecretKeySpec.java:94)
        at org.wso2.carbon.connector.amazons3.auth.AmazonS3Authentication.getAut
horizationHeaderValue(AmazonS3Authentication.java:79)
        at org.wso2.carbon.connector.amazons3.auth.AmazonS3AuthConnector.connect
(AmazonS3AuthConnector.java:102)
        at org.wso2.carbon.connector.core.AbstractConnector.mediate(AbstractConn
ector.java:32)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.ext.ClassMediator.mediate(ClassMediator.
java:78)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractLis
tMediator.java:81)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractLis
tMediator.java:48)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.TemplateMediator.mediate(Templa
teMediator.java:97)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.InvokeMediator.mediate(InvokeMe
diator.java:129)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.InvokeMediator.mediate(InvokeMe
diator.java:78)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractLis
tMediator.java:81)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractLis
tMediator.java:48)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMe
diator.java:149)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(Pro
xyServiceMessageReceiver.java:175)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportListener.handleIncom
ingMessage(AbstractTransportListener.java:328)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.processFile(VFS
TransportListener.java:751)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.scanFileOrDirec
tory(VFSTransportListener.java:407)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.poll(VFSTranspo
rtListener.java:177)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.poll(VFSTranspo
rtListener.java:124)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractPollingTransportListener$1$1.
run(AbstractPollingTransportListener.java:67)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(Native
WorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

When looking through the code it seems that the key should be there as the custom InvalidKeyException is not being thrown but rather the java.lang.IllegalArgumentException is being thrown by javax.crypto.

My mediator config.

```
<amazons3.getAuthorization>
    <accessKeyId>********************</accessKeyId>
    <secretAccessKey>****************************************</secretAccessKey>
    <methodType>POST</methodType>
    <contentType>multipart/form-data</contentType>
    <bucketName>*********</bucketName>
    <uriRemainder>/</uriRemainder>
    <isXAmzDate>true</isXAmzDate>
</amazons3.getAuthorization>
```

What am I doing wrong? Anyone has any experience with this? Does this function work for others?

Answer (score 0):

This error has been resolved. Apparently setting a property with the key fields fixes the problem.